# How to print one row based on the date with python pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm writing a program that gives the bank statement, and you can search for it by the date, it reads your extract and gives you how much you spent that day, but I'm with a big problem, I get it to search by the date but it does not print the whole role, just the date 
here`s the code that I've writen

```
def analyzePdf(self, pdf_file=None):
    call_result = {}
    debug_data = []
    return_msg = "BankAccountReport:analyzePdf"
    if type(pdf_file) != str:
        return_msg += "input validation failed: pdf_file must be an string that sets where the document is"
        return {{'success': RC.input_validation_failed, 'return_msg': return_msg, 'debug_data': debug_data}}

    df = wrapper.read_pdf(pdf_file, pages= "all", output_format="csv")

    df.to_csv("output.csv")
    df = pd.read_csv("output.csv", usecols=['Data',"Docto.", "Saldo (R$)"])
    print(df)
    df.to_csv("output2.csv")

    inp = pd.to_datetime(input('please enter the date: '), format="%d/%m/%Y")
    print(df[(df['Data'] == inp)])
```

here is the output that I'm getting:

```
please enter the date: 07/10/2019
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Data, Docto., Saldo (R$)]
Index: []
```

and the expected output would be

```
07/10/2019 R$ 809,22
```

Comment: Is the `'Data'` column datetime format? What if you treat both values as string? (That is conver the `Data` column to object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but it looks like you want to filter your dataframe by the date.

```
df = df[df['Data'].str.contains(str(inp))]
```

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
    a.analyzePdf("Document.pdf")
  File "C:/Desktop/Projeto automacao financeira/pdf.py", line 33, in analyzePdf
    df = df[df['Data'].str.contains(str(inp))]
  File "C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2985, in __getitem__
    if com.is_bool_indexer(key):
  File "C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\common.py", line 130, in is_bool_indexer
    raise ValueError(na_msg)
ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values
`

Comment: Looks like you have NaN or blank values in the dataframe. 
Might be able to fix that by filling blanks with an ignorable value like.

```df = df.fillna("Blank")```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the format matches for both values (the one on the columns, and the one being passed as `inp`) because that seems to be issue, one being a string and the other a datetime object. Other than that, your code should work fine for the most part. Here I can prove it with an example:

import pandas as pd

```
data = {'Data':['20/02/2019','25/08/2019','21/09/2019'],'Saldo (R$)':[800,300,504]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data'],format='%d/%m/%Y')
inp = pd.to_datetime(input('please enter date: '), format='%d/%m/%Y')

print(df)
print("filtered: ")
print(df[df['Data'] == inp])
```

Output:

```
please enter date: 21/09/2019
        Data  Saldo (R$)
0 2019-02-20         800
1 2019-08-25         300
2 2019-09-21         504
filtered:
        Data  Saldo (R$)
2 2019-09-21         504
```

Comment: But what should I change in that piece of code? since the column that mathes are "Data" and "Saldo"

Comment: but they are on the csv file